# How to find total available and used memory using df command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, vi

I have

```
-bash-4.1$ df -l 
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       16126920  8557072   6750648  56% /
tmpfs           33026676        0  33026676   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda5      151897244 51004788  93176464  36% /state/partition1
/dev/sda2        4031680   358884   3467996  10% /var
```

Now I need to get total available disk space count except tmpfs . 
Now I need to get total available disk space count except tmpfs .

What are the commands to get the total available disk and used disk?

Comment: `df` reports disk usage, not memory.

Comment: `df` is not a tool that deals with memory. hint `man df`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to unix.stackexchange.com or askubuntu.com

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: sorry i want total of used and available disk space . updated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> to get the total available disk and used disk?

```
df -lh --total /dev/sda*
```

**----------**

To exclude only type `tmpfs`:

```
df -lh --total -x tmpfs
```

Comment: if it is /dev/sda format its fine. if its in some other form above command wont work

Comment: @sagarreddy, you have my update